# How to format titles of table of contents, list of abbreviations, abstract and so on

Tags: formatting, chapters

I am writing my dissertation in report format in latex.I am wondering how I could have titles of acknowledgements, table of contents, list of symbols, list of abbreviations, list of figures, list of tables and abstract as shown below, that is, written in CAPITALS, placed to the right and with a  line fitted to the page below the text.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Would you like all unnumbered chapters with this layout? And do they have to be in the table of contents (except, probably, the table of contents itself)?

Comment: I already have numbered chapters in this format, but could not have the ones above.

Comment: I meant *all* UNnumbered chapters (including bibliography, index , &c.). Did you use `titlesec`?

Comment: Have you already looked at `titletoc` package?

Comment: @Bernard, Sorry! Yes, this is exactly what I want.

Comment: @giusva, No, never heard of it I am afraid

Comment: @Gunal Well.. now you have. The solution Bernard gave you is exactly with that package. titlesec, titleps and titletoc are all parts of the same package (titlesec). The first is to handle chapters, sections, etc. The second to handle header and footer. The third to handle table of contents. Even if Bernard already answered you I suggest you to have a look at the manual, is very short and it's one of the most used package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would do it, using the `numberless`  key from `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}[block]{\bfseries\huge\filleft}{}{0em}{\MakeUppercase}[{\titlerule[1pt]}]
\titleformat{name=\chapter}[display]{\bfseries\huge\filleft}{\chaptername~\thechapter}{3ex}{\MakeUppercase}[{\titlerule[1pt]}]

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\chapter{First chapter}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Dummy figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad to feel helpful!

Comment: Bernard, I need to increase the space between "FIRST CHAPTER" and the horizontal line. How can I do that?